# Parsing nested Json using Json.Net

Tags: c#, json

I'm new to Json and trying to understand how  I can parse it using Json.Net. I've tried to create objects for my json input, but I'm stuck. I'm not quite sure how to parse the input so I can iterate through it and output the season numbers and episode name.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Json:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "1921":{  
         "1":{  
            "airdate":"1921-03-20",
            "name":"Cleaning Up!!?",
            "quality":"N/A",
            "status":"Wanted"
         },
         "2":{  
            "airdate":"1921-03-20",
            "name":"Kansas City Girls Are Rolling Their Own Now",
            "quality":"N/A",
            "status":"Wanted"
         },
         "3":{  
            "airdate":"1921-03-20",
            "name":"Did You Ever Take a Ride Over Kansas City Street 'in a Fliver'",
            "quality":"N/A",
            "status":"Wanted"
         },
         "4":{  
            "airdate":"1921-03-20",
            "name":"Kansas City's Spring Clean-Up",
            "quality":"N/A",
            "status":"Wanted"
         }
      },
      "1923":{  
         "1":{  
            "airdate":"2013-05-16",
            "name":"Alice's Wonderland - aka - Alice in Slumberland",
            "quality":"Unknown",
            "status":"Downloaded"
         }
      }
   },
   "message":"",
   "result":"success"
}
```

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\json\input.txt"));
            foreach (var e in data)
            {
                // Being able to output Season and Episode name like:
                // 1921 - Cleaning Up!!?
            }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public Dictionary<int, Season> data { get; set; }
            public string message { get; set; }
            public string result { get; set; }
        }

        public class Season
        {
            public Dictionary<string, Episode> number { get; set; }
        }

        public class Episode
        {
            public string airdate { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string quality { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Are you getting an error?

Comment: What does `data` look like after deserializing? Is it populated? In your `RootObject` you have a `Dictionary` called `data` so you'd need to iterate over `data.data` to start with.

Comment: yeah, is the RootObject populated? Are you getting an exception? Your code looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a change to your `RootObject`:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, Episode>> data { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }
}
```

You can then do this:

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
foreach (var s in root.data)
{
    foreach (var e in s.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", s.Key, e.Value.name));
        // access whatever properties you want here...
    }
}
```

Note, we have eliminated the `Season` object because JSON.net won't be able to map to the property `number` because that's not a property in your original JSON (you can make it work, but it would require some fiddling around with custom serialization).

If you *really* want a LINQ solution, then something like:

```
root.data.ToList().ForEach(s =>
{
    s.Value.ToList().ForEach(e =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", s.Key, e.Value.name));
    });
});
```

Achieves the same thing, but requires copying your dictionary into a list which might be a problem if your dictionary is very large.

Comment: LINQ with Lambdas are a LOT more concise and readable.... use them to get ahead! (See below for an example). Additionally, Model objects shouldn't have business logic in them....

Comment: @nterry: Concise? yes. Readable? *very debatable*. As for business logic, there's no business logic here. The models only define the way the data is structured.

Comment: Linq is very readable. You just need to get used to it. just use a Select if ForEach isnt available.

Comment: @nterry: Are you suggesting two `foreach` loops aren't readable? I use LINQ *all the time*, but I don't think it's really necessary here.

Comment: @nterry I agree with Matt. Beside debatable improvement of readability in the LINQ (it's not even LINQ) version it needs to materialize the whole query via `.ToList()` before iteration (only lists have `ForEach` - your suggestion to use `Select` is wrong), which is really unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a so in-depth answer!